# 'ASN1 corrupted data' in X509Certificate2 object

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 object contains values 'ASN1 corrupted data' instead of certificate data. The object is created by called constructor with pfx certificate file as binary and password as arguments.
The problem occures in Xamarin Android app only, exactly the same line (and the same .pfx file) in Windows .NET application generates the right object with data.

`var certificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(certFileExternalPath), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9OCN.png)

What can I do to read this certificate in Xamarin? I need X509Certificate2 (or X509Certificate) .net object to use it with RestSharp client.

Comment: There is a possibly related [issue on Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15073#issuecomment-619422356) that is hopefully fixed in .Net 7, according to the tracking link on that issue. I didn’t find any similar issue for Android. You could create a new issue there, for Android. Maybe link to the other issue, ask if it might be related. If it is fixed in .Net 7, consider migrating from Xamarin to Maui.